# Can a non-trivial factor of a strong Fermat-pseudoprime always be found efficiently?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, pseudoprimes

Suppose, $N$ is a composite Fermat-pseudoprime to base $a$ :

$$a^{N-1}\equiv 1\ (\ mod \ N)$$

If $N$ is NOT strong Fermat-pseudoprime to base $a$, a non-trivial factor of $N$ can be found efficiently. So, lets assume $N$ is strong Fermat-pseudoprime to base $a$.

> Is there always a number $b$, such that $b^{N-1}\equiv 1 \ (\ mod\ N)$ holds,
>   but $N$ is NOT strong Fermat-pseudoprime to base $b$ ? If such a base can be found, a non-trivial factor of $N$ can be found efficiently.

If $N$ is a Carmichael-number, the answer is yes because every $b$ with $(b,N)=1$, such that $N$ is NOT strong Fermat-pseudoprime to base $b$
does the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't always a base that is a pseudoprime but not a strong pseudoprime.

For example, 121 is a pseudoprime to bases 3, 9, 27, 40, 81, 94, 112, and 118 (and no others).  It is also a strong pseudoprime to those bases as $b^{15}\equiv\pm 1 \pmod {121}$.